# How would you convert a column delimited character to a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a number of results that I want to be grouped.

An example grouping is

```
> results$netting$codes[[1]]
[1] "7,4,5,9,39"
```

If I hard code the group I get the results I'm looking for.

```
dplyr::filter(xCategories,xCategories$code %in% c( 7,4,5,9,39 ))
   code frequency percentage
1     4       124  20.462046
2     4       124  20.462046
3     4       124  20.462046
4     4       124  20.462046
5     5       112  18.481848
6     5       112  18.481848
7     5       112  18.481848
8     5       112  18.481848
9     7        65  10.726073
10    7        65  10.726073
11    7        65  10.726073
12    7        65  10.726073
13    9        64  10.561056
14    9        64  10.561056
15    9        64  10.561056
16    9        64  10.561056
17   39         8   1.320132
```

If I reference the group I get no results.

```
> dplyr::filter(xCategories,xCategories$code %in% c( results$netting$codes[[1]] ))
[1] code       frequency  percentage
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

or

```
> dplyr::filter(xCategories,xCategories$code %in% c( as.vector(results$netting$codes[[1]]) ))
[1] code       frequency  percentage
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

How would you convert a column delimited character to a vector in R?

Comment: You usually don't want `$` in dplyr functions, as it references the whole variable instead of the inline instance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: dplyr uses non-standard evaluation that accepts bare column names (without a `some_df$` prefix). If you use the prefix, you're not referencing the data passed into the function, but grabbing a vector from outside. Prefixing works fine for simple calls, and can occasionally be helpful to create very complicated ones, but the majority of the time will just cause you headaches.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as off-topic?  What is off-topic about it?  OP just wants to convert `"7,4,5,9,39"` to a numeric vector.  The rest of the question is irrelevant, really.

Comment: I didn't understand the downvote either. The question illustrates what I tried, what I was looking and the results I did not get. I also knew that I had to turn a comma delimited string into a vector. Downvoting without an explanation is very unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your right-hand side, you may want to use `scan()`.  It can read a delimited character string and convert the result to numeric automatically.

```
scan(text = results$netting$codes[[1]], sep = ",")
```

Examples:

```
scan(text = "7,4,5,9,39", sep = ",")
# Read 5 items
# [1]  7  4  5  9 39

1:10 %in% scan(text = "7,4,5,9,39", sep = ",")
# Read 5 items
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: dplyr::filter(xCategories,xCategories$code %in% c( scan(text = results$netting$codes[[1]], sep = ",") )) gives the result I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison - As alistaire mentioned, you don't need `$`.  You also don't need `c()`.  So your code could be simplified to `dplyr::filter(xCategories, code %in% scan(text = results$netting$codes[[1]], sep = ","))`